# How can I force SQLAlchemy to use a specific schema when generating a query?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to automatically create a Table object from a database table (in AWS Redshift) and query it using the following code:

```
TABLE_NAME = table1
SCHEMA_NAME = schema1

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute(f'SET search_path TO {SCHEMA_NAME}') # doesn't seem to to anything
    metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=session.bind)
    metadata.reflect(engine, only=[TABLE_NAME])
    Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
    Base.prepare(reflect=True, schema=SCHEMA_NAME) # this argument doesn't seem to to anything either
    table_obj = Base.classes[TABLE_NAME]
    results = session.query(table_obj).all()
```

However the query generated by SQLAlchemy does not prepend the schema name to the table name. It generates something like `select col1 from table1` instead of `select col1 from schema1.table1`.

How can I force it to do so?

I'm using `automap_base`, so I don't think I can use `__table_args__ = {"schema":"schema_name"}` (a solution I've found elsewhere).